# Blueprism unable to match two data items that are the same

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have an object which is trying to determine if a value it reads from on screen is the same as that passed to the object. This is a validation step and it doesn't appear to recognize them when they are the same. I have also tried trimming and lowering both values. I have also tried Test Regex Match.
Is there any way that I can get the object to recognize that they are the same, or is there a way for me to find out why they are not matching?[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use a Remove Non Word Characters Action in Utility Strings.
[image]

Comment: Nice, I forgot this function was there :)

Comment: I suspect it was the space, sometimes the space on websites use `&nbsp;`, which is actually not the same as a normal space!

Comment: Hmmmm would that have escaped the trim?

Answer (score 2):

A strange thing. If direct comparison failed, even after trimming and with regex failed, there is probably something wrong with some of the characters. I would probably guess the spaces. Have you experienced this behaviour even on values without spaces?

Anyway, I would probably build a C# code stage like this, that accepts `txt` (string) and outputs `col` (collection):

```
col = new DataTable();
col.Columns.Add("Pos", typeof(decimal));
col.Columns.Add("Char", typeof(string));
col.Columns.Add("CharNum", typeof(decimal));

char[] arr = txt.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow row = col.NewRow();

    row["Pos"] = i;
    row["Char"] = arr[i];
    row["CharNum"] = (int)arr[i];

    col.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

The result would be like this:

[image]

Try to run the code stage on both of your values and see if there is a visible discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you for this, I actually worked out a solution, but this is very helpful for the future.

Comment: @esqew It's posted as the answer?

Comment: @E_McAndrew My apologies - somehow missed it!